# iOS 4 Build SDK

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

I installed the iOS 4 SDK yesterday. I previously had the 3.1.2, 3.1.3 and 3.2 SDKs installed. Since installing the iOS 4 SDK, I only have 3.2 and 4.0 available in Xcode. When I load an Xcode project that was targeting an older version (say 3.1.2), it says "Base SDK Missing" in the toolbar.

I've been able to reset the project to target iOS 4 instead - and have successfully built. However, I need to do some ad hoc builds for users who may not have iOS 4 installed on their devices yet. If I give them a build that was done for iOS 4 (not using any iOS 4 features - it's the same code I used to build with 3.1.2), will this execute on their device ok?

Unfortunately I don't have any non-upgraded devices to test this on myself!

Thanks,

John

Comment: There are a bunch of these types of questions, so I've tried to bind them all together to a community wiki, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To target older iPhone OS's with the new iOS 4 SDK, Select your XCode project -> Get Info, and then select "iPhone Device 4.0" as the Base SDK, and then select the lowest iPhone OS version from iPhone OS Deployment Target that you need to support with your ad hoc app.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I ended up doing. I've heard that Apple won't be accepting any new App Store submissions unless they have been built with the 3.2 or 4.0 SDK now anyway - if so, this looks like the only option by which older devices could be targeted.

Comment: That's my understanding as well, which I've detailed in a community wiki. Link is in comment to question above.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to install XCode beta to an alternative folder /DeveloperBeta (for example) and use the stable xcode for older SDK builds.

You can still do that actually.